# How do I get the HTML code for my ggplotly plot

Tags: html, r, ggplot2, plotly

The code below builds an interactive plot that I would like to integrate into my wordpress article:

```
# interactive plot with ribbon
test <- ggplot(data = wide.data, aes(x = x, y = pred)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lwr, ymax = upr, fill = model), alpha = .5) + 
  geom_point(aes( group = model, fill = model)) + 
  labs(x = "Number of Games Played", y = "Total Number of Goals") + scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,70,5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,50,5))

ggplotly(test)
```

I need to translate the plot i'm given into HTML and i'm not quite sure how to do that.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you open your plot in a browser you can right click > view page source (or inspect element, depending on which you prefer)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have much experience with HTML. Would I copy and paste the entire page source into Wordpress or whatever is within the script?

Comment: maybe something like the [RWordPress](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/wordpress/) is what you're after?

Comment: Ive looked into that a bit, but i'm having trouble utilizing Rmarkdown and Knitr. I guess I'll ask another question related to that.

Comment: Are you unfamiliar with `Rmarkdown` itself? if so [their website](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) has a lot of useful resources

Comment: Yea, I also looked there but the thing that is confusing me is how I go from my .R file to the .RMD file.

Comment: Maybe [this blog](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/rmarkdown.html) or [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-apyD5f9nwg) will help?

Comment: The very basic premise is to put your R code inside 'code chunks' (a code chunk is a paragraph of text with three back-ticks (`) above/below it)

Comment: the _entire_ code? So do you usually just copy and paste you code you used to build your models and data frame into one of those 'code chunks'?

Comment: yes - or you can put a `source(yourRfile.R)` inside a code chunk too. Then, outside the chunk you put any text you want (usually to explain what's inside the chunk).

Comment: awesome, i'll try that. Would you recommend I do all of my plotting outside of my R script and inside of the R Markdown or does that not matter?

Comment: If you upload a plotly plot to the plotly website, you can embed it into the html code (on your blog) with an iframe. I've had trouble copying html for interactive apps from rmarkdown into free web hosting because of the size of the html.

Comment: That's hard to say without knowing the purpose of your document. However, what's the point of a plot if it's not presenting something to someone? (Therefore I think it makes sense to include all your plots in the markdown document, as that's what people will see?)

Comment: @SymbolixAU ; Can you post an answer? It would be more useful that a set of disjointed comments.